# difference between appdelegate and delegate in viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to integrate one sample code with (for example SampleCode project) my iPhone application .In the sample code in firstViewController is added in MainWindow.xib and linked to `viewController` created in the below code.

```
@interface SampleCodeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    firstViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet firstViewController *viewController;
```

and viewController instantiated with initWithCoder and when firstView is appeared on tap of button Camera can be opened be calling OpenCamera method as in the below code.

```
//in firstViewController.mm file

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {

    }

    [self initLocal];

    return self;
}
//to open camera in SampleCode application
    - (IBAction)OpenCamera {

        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        SampleCodeAppDelegate* delegate = [app delegate];
        UIViewController* uiViewCont = [delegate viewController];
        ((CCamera*)m_pCamera)->Camera(uiViewCont);
    }
```

In my navigation based application (MyApplication) I want to call firstViewController of SampleCode with one of viewController MyApplicationViewControllerA directly without adding to MyApplicationAppDelegate.

So I want to if I am creating the delegate in MyApplicationViewControllerA viewController that should work as the appdelegate in SampleCode application.
I am not able to open the camera but after closing the camera I am not able to open any other view of  MyApplication except MyApplicationViewControllerA. 
I am trying pushViewController and modalViewController not able to render other View.

I am not confused about the delegate. So I want to know what is the difference between AppDelegate(in `SampleCodeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>`) and delegate declared in other ViewContrller.

Comment: [self initLocal]; should be inside your "if (self = [super init...)" block. If the super init failed, you don't want to be trying to set your object up; just return self (which will be nil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am trying pushViewController and modalViewController not able to render other View.**

**answer:**
If you are not able to show other view after camera overlay screen then I think you need to show other view by performing action on main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showOtherView) withObject:OtherViewControllerObj waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and in the showOtherView selector method first you need to confirm that you should push the viewconroller in the navigationconroll and if that is already pushed then you should try to show otherview using presentModalViewController like below code.

```
-(void)showOtherView{

[self.navigationController pushViewController:OtherViewControllerObj animated:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:OtherViewControllerObj animated:YES]; 

}
```

I think this should work.